# xgboost always predict 1 level with imbalance dataset

Tags: r, xgboost

I'm using xgboost to build a model. The dataset only has 200 rows and 10000 cols.

I tried chi-2 to get 100 cols, but my confusion matrix looks like this:

```
    1 0
1 190 0
0  10 0
```

I tried to use 10000 attributes, randomly select 100 attributes, select 100 attributes according to chi-2, but I never get 0 case predicted. Is it because of the dataset, or because the way I use xgboost?

My factor(pred.cv) is always showing only 1 level, while factor(y+1) has 1 or 2 as levels.

```
param <- list("objective" = "binary:logistic",
          "eval_metric" = "error",
          "nthread" = 2,
          "max_depth" = 5,
          "eta" = 0.3,
          "gamma" = 0,
          "subsample" = 0.8,
          "colsample_bytree" = 0.8,
          "min_child_weight" = 1,
          "max_delta_step"= 5,
          "learning_rate" =0.1,
          "n_estimators" = 1000,
          "seed"=27,
          "scale_pos_weight" = 1
          )
nfold=3
nrounds=200
pred.cv = matrix(bst.cv$pred, nrow=length(bst.cv$pred)/1, ncol=1)
pred.cv = max.col(pred.cv, "last")
factor(y+1) # this is the target in train, level 1 and 2
factor(pred.cv) # this is the issue, it is always only 1 level
```

Comment: What is the proportion of the 1/2 levels in factor(y+1)?. If imbalanced perhaps try changing scale_pos_weight.

Comment: @missuse  only 10%, I will try that first!

Comment: @missuse I think I have some clue. from online it says to do this: "pred.cv = matrix(bst.cv$pred, nrow=length(bst.cv$pred)/num.class, ncol=num.class)", but when I do this, num.class = 2, my confusionMatrix(factor(y+1), factor(pred.cv)) returns error "all arguments must have the same length". Because factor(y+1) is 980, but factor(pred.cv) is 980/2. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Try `pred.cv = ifelse(bst$pred < 0.5, 0, 1)` and `table(pred.cv, y)`.

Comment: @missuse I actually figure that out 5 minutes ago, that I didn't convert prob. to yes or no :/ thanks!

Comment: @missuse I actually find that scale_pos_weight very important, to change my results. But I am still trying to get the best parameters to get higher accuracy. Do you have any idea what is the best way to do it? I tried caret package, it can tune some parameters. But I'd prefer something that increase the accuracy of predict minority cases to a much higher value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

test

```
param <- list("objective" = "binary:logistic",
      "eval_metric" = "error",
      "nthread" = 2,
      "max_depth" = 5,
      "eta" = 0.3,
      "gamma" = 0,
      "subsample" = 0.8,
      "colsample_bytree" = 0.8,
      "min_child_weight" = 1,
      "max_delta_step"= 5,
      "learning_rate" =0.1,
      "n_estimators" = 1000,
      "seed"=27,
      "scale_pos_weight" = 1
      )
nfold=3
nrounds=200
pred.cv = matrix(bst.cv$pred, nrow=length(bst.cv$pred)/1, ncol=1)
pred.cv = max.col(pred.cv, "last")
factor(y+1) # this is the target in train, level 1 and 2
factor(pred.cv) # this is the issue, it is always only 1 level
```

Comment: If there is a difference between what was posted in the question and this answer then it would be very helpful to have an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I found caret to be slow and it is not able to tune all the parameters of xgboost models without building a custom model which is quite more complicated than using ones own custom function for evaluation.

However if you are doing some up/down sampling or smote/rose caret is the way to go since it incorporates them correctly in the model evaluating phase (during re-sampling). See: https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html

However I found these techniques have a very small impact on the results and usually for the worse, at least in the models I trained.

`scale_pos_weight` gives a higher weight to a certain class, if the minority class is at 10% abundance then playing with `scale_pos_weight` around `5 - 10`  should be beneficial.

Tuning regularization parameters can be quite beneficial for xgboost: here one has several parameters: `alpha`, `beta` and `gamma` - I found valid values to be 0 - 3. Other useful parameters that add direct regularization (by adding uncertainty) are `subsample`, `colsample_bytree` and `colsample_bylevel`. I found that playing with `colsample_bylevel` can also have a positive outcome on the model. `subsample` and `colsample_bytree` you are already utilizing.

I would test a much smaller eta and more trees to see if the model benefits. `early_stopping_rounds` rounds can speed up the process in that case.

Other `eval_metric` are probably going to be more beneficial than accuracy. Try `logloss` or `auc` and even `map` and `ndcg`

Here is a function for grid search of hyper-parameters. It uses `auc` as evaluation metric but one can change that easily

```
xgb.par.opt=function(train, seed){
  require(xgboost)
  ntrees=2000
  searchGridSubCol <- expand.grid(subsample = c(0.5, 0.75, 1), 
                                  colsample_bytree = c(0.6, 0.8, 1),
                                  gamma = c(0, 1, 2),
                                  eta = c(0.01, 0.03),
                                  max_depth = c(4,6,8,10))
  aucErrorsHyperparameters <- apply(searchGridSubCol, 1, function(parameterList){

    #Extract Parameters to test
    currentSubsampleRate <- parameterList[["subsample"]]
    currentColsampleRate <- parameterList[["colsample_bytree"]]
    currentGamma <- parameterList[["gamma"]]
    currentEta =parameterList[["eta"]]
    currentMaxDepth =parameterList[["max_depth"]]
    set.seed(seed)

    xgboostModelCV <- xgb.cv(data = train, 
                             nrounds = ntrees,
                             nfold = 5,
                             objective = "binary:logistic",
                             eval_metric= "auc",
                             metrics = "auc",
                             verbose = 1,
                             print_every_n = 50,
                             early_stopping_rounds = 200,
                             stratified = T,
                             scale_pos_weight=sum(all_data[train,1]==0)/sum(all_data[train,1]==1),
                             max_depth = currentMaxDepth, 
                             eta = currentEta, 
                             gamma = currentGamma,
                             colsample_bytree = currentColsampleRate,
                             min_child_weight = 1,
                             subsample =  currentSubsampleRate
                             seed = seed) 


    xvalidationScores <- as.data.frame(xgboostModelCV$evaluation_log)

    auc = xvalidationScores[xvalidationScores$iter==xgboostModelCV$best_iteration,c(1,4,5)]
    auc = cbind(auc, currentSubsampleRate, currentColsampleRate, currentGamma, currentEta,  currentMaxDepth)
    names(auc) = c("iter", "test.auc.mean", "test.auc.std", "subsample", "colsample", "gamma", "eta", "max.depth")
    print(auc)
    return(auc)
  })
  return(aucErrorsHyperparameters)
}
```

One can add other parameters to the `expand.grid` call.

I usually train hyper-parameters on one CV repetition and evaluate them on additional repetitions with other seeds or on the validation set (but doing it on validation set should be used with caution to avoid over-fitting)